# Weird characters being returned from the Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, character-encoding

I am using the Twitter API to get the tweets from my team's Twitter account for the team website. Some of the tweets contain special characters, and those characters are being returned via the API in a weird state. For instance:

`;-)`

is being returned as:

`â€¦`

I would like the smiley face to show up as opposed to the symbols that are currently showing. I have tried using the following functions to correct this, but none have worked:

- html_entitiy_decode
- utf8_decode
- utf8_encode
- htmlspecialchars
- htmlspecialchars_decode

I have also added:

```
<meta charset="utf8">
```

to my document head.

None of these attempts solved my problem, what else should I try?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `htmlentities($yourvar, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');`?

Comment: Show us `bin2hex($string)` of that string to see what it actually contains.

Comment: @AmalMurali I just did, and that just gave me 3 dots as opposed to the random characters.

Comment: @deceze For the entire tweet in question, this is what I get from that function: 52542040536f6c6172526163696e675f6f72673a204974207365656d732074686174207768696c6520696e20736f6c617220726163696e6720746865207472656e6420697320746f206d6f76652066726f6d203320746f203420776865656c7320287479726573292c20696e20466f726d756c61204f6e652069742069732065786163746c792074686520e280a6

Comment: The string “â€¦” most probably results from misinterpreting the UTF-8 encoded representation of U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS “…” as if the data were windows-1252 (Windows Latin 1) encoded. So you probably get a wrong character in a wrong encoding.

Comment: What he said ^. You're not handling encodings correctly, the string itself it fine when interpreted as UTF-8: http://3v4l.org/EJqIB See [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/) and [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/) for starters.